# Nested_form_for with field_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my view is

```
<h3> Register New Items </h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="span2 offset4">
    <%= nested_form_for @item_category, :url => items_path, :method => :post, :html => { :class => "item_category"} do |f| %>
        <div><%= f.label :item_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :item_name %></div>
        </br>

        <div>
            <%= f.fields_for :item_companies do |f| %>
                  <%= f.label :company_name %>
                <%= f.text_field :company_name %>

     </div>
     </br>

     <%= f.fields_for :item_weights do |f| %>
            <div>
                    <%= f.label :weight %>
                    <%= f.text_field :weight %>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div>
                    <%= f.label :price %>
                    <%= f.text_field :price %>
            </div>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>

    <div><%= f.submit "Submit" %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and controller

```
def new
  @item_category = ItemCategory.new
  item_company = @item_category.item_companies.build
  item_company.item_weights.build 
end
```

and when I have applied debugger in `create` action and I saw value of  `params[:item_category]` and this is generated `{"item_name"=>"iname", "item_companies_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"company_name"=>"cname", "item_weights_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"weight"=>"20kg", "price"=>"100"}}}}}`

```
ItemCategory.new(params[:item_category])
```

generated error

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error Exception: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: item_companies_attributes.
```

Where i am wrong and how to save value in three tables using this.

Comment: Is this problem will solve using HAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to add this piece of code in your `ItemCategory` model:

```
attr_accessible :item_companies_attributes
```

which will allow you to set these attributes.